# KEDA autoscaler metric support

Tags: kubernetes, keda

My current k8 hpa setup is a vanilla setup that uses a combination of 2 metrics.

1. a Pods Metric (each pod emits a metric related to a business logic value) and the target is an average of X (injected into prometheus and read from prometheus)
2. an External Metric that looks at SQS Queue Size (injected into prometheus and read from prometheus) and the target is an average of Y

the final pod count is the max suggested pod count of the 2 metrics. The question is, I want to use KEDA to have the scale to 0 feature, but will KEDA be able to support these same 2 metrics in the same way?

nothing yet...haven't tried anything, researching